# Sql query for tree like table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
Id  ParentName ChildName
1    COM1        SERV1
2    COM1        SERV2
3    SERV2       APP1
4    APP1        VS1
```

The above table could be represented as a tree structure as below:

```
Level 1: COM1
Level 2   SERV1, SERV2
Level 3:           APP1
Level 4:              VS1
```

I would like to be able to retrieve all the child and recursive child as below:

```
A      B
COM1 SERV1
     SERV2
     APP1
     VS1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is your SQL Flavor (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.)? Add it as a platform-specific tag.

Comment: I use SQL Server

Comment: See if this is helpful: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL employee hierarchy recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61965915/t-sql-employee-hierarchy-recursive-query)